# send sentences(string) with form jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, checkbox

This "form" part is contained in a jsp file.

The variable `risposte[j]` is a string of this type: "L'altopiano della meseta",
`domandechiuse[i]` is another sentence and I inserted, between the two sentences, the character: ";;" as separator.

When I send the form data to the servlet I can not receive (using `request.getParameterValues`) the full value of the string. Only I receive the first word of the first sentence, when it encounters space is as if it stopped sending.

The result should be : "L'altopiano della meseta;;Testo della domanda",
but i receive only : "L'altopiano"

How can I receive the whole sentence?

```
<span>Risposta: </span>
<label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="domande" name="domande"><%out.print(risposte[j]);%></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="risposta" value=<%out.print(risposte[j]+";;"+domandechiuse[i]);%>><br/>
</label>>
```

Comment: **However, the problem is neither the string setting nor the space. The problem is the checkbox that only sends the first word to the first space. I do not know if I should use another <input type> instead of the checkbox or change the <value> tag. As I am planning a questionnaire in part I am obliged to use the checkbox. How can I fix it?**